# Subset rows in an R dataframe based on partial match of multiple strings

Tags: r, grepl

I don't think this exact question has been asked - lots of stuff on subsetting based on one value (i.e., `x[grepl("some string", x[["column1"]]),]`), but not multiple values/strings.

Here is an example of my data:

```
#create sample data frame
data = data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4), phrase = c("dog, frog, cat, moose", "horse, bunny, mouse", "armadillo, cat, bird,", "monkey, chimp, cow"))

#convert the `phrase` column to character string (the dataset I'm working on requires this)
data$phrase = data$phrase

#list of strings to remove rows by
remove_if = c("dog", "cat")
```

This will give a dataset that looks like:

```
  id                phrase
1  1 dog, frog, cat, moose
2  2   horse, bunny, mouse
3  3 armadillo, cat, bird,
4  4    monkey, chimp, cow
```

I want to remove row 1 and row 3 (because row 1 contains "dog" and row 3 contains "cat"), but keep row 2 and row 4.

```
  id                phrase
1  2   horse, bunny, mouse
2  4    monkey, chimp, cow
```

In other words, I want to subset `data` so that it is only (the headers and) row 2 and row 4 (because they contain neither "dog" nor "cat").

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `grepl` with `subset` after `paste`ing the 'remove_if' to a single string

```
subset(data, !grepl(paste(remove_if, collapse="|"), phrase))
#    id              phrase
#2  2 horse, bunny, mouse
#4  4  monkey, chimp, cow
```

Comment: Worked as expected on the real dataset - thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In case you want to mix it with `dplyr` and `stringr`:

```r
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  filter(str_detect(phrase, paste(remove_if, collapse = "|"), negate = TRUE))
#   id              phrase
# 1  2 horse, bunny, mouse
# 2  4  monkey, chimp, cow
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `grep`

```
> data[grep(paste0(remove_if, collapse = "|"), data$phrase, invert = TRUE), ]
  id              phrase
2  2 horse, bunny, mouse
4  4  monkey, chimp, cow
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data[!grepl(paste0("(^|, )(", paste0(remove_if, collapse = "|"), ")(,|$)"), data$phrase),]

# id                    phrase
#  2 caterpillar, bunny, mouse
#  4        monkey, chimp, cow
```

the regex constructed in this example is `"(^|, )(dog|cat)(,|$)"`, to avoid matching words that contain 'cat' or 'dog', but aren't actually the exact words, e.g. 'caterpillar'

Answer (score 0):

An another way (maybe not the best one):

```
data[-unique(unlist(sapply(c(remove_if),function(x){grep(x,data$phrase)}))),]
  id              phrase
2  2 horse, bunny, mouse
4  4  monkey, chimp, cow
```